# Start clicking with a key press

Tags: autoit

I am very new to programming and this is probably a very easy question, but I just cannot do it.

I have a task to click on an object several times then stop it, move my mouse manually to other object and click there several times. I would like to move my mouse to the object manually, press <kbd>F2</kbd>, click a few times

So far my program looks like this. When I run it nothing happens when I press <kbd>F2</kbd>. It should click. The <kbd>F1</kbd> exit works however.

```
Func MyExit()
    Exit
EndFunc

HotKeySet("{F1}", "MyExit")

While 1
   Sleep(1000)
WEnd



Func clicking()

   MouseClick("primary")

EndFunc

HotKeySet("{F2}", "clicking")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HotKeySet function for the F2 key is at the end of your script, which means it will never actually be executed. To fix, simply put it before the While loop

```
Func MyExit()
    Exit
EndFunc

HotKeySet("{F1}", "MyExit")
HotKeySet("{F2}", "clicking")
While 1
   Sleep(1000)
WEnd



Func clicking()

   MouseClick("primary")

EndFunc
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. I didn't think of it :)